# Using returned promise data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, promise

I have something like:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
   results : function(){

      return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){

        Ember.$.getJSON('/search').then(function(res){
          console.log('response data is: ', res);
          resolve(res)
        })

      })

   }.property(),
  ...
})

// data
$.mockjax({
  url: '/search',
  responseText : {
    type: 'different people',
    res: [
      {name: 'charlie', age: '55'},
      {name: 'bobby', age: '19'},
      {name: 'raymond', age: '39'}
    ]
  }
})
```

[my jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ricexunana/edit)

How do I actually use the returned data? Currently, `results` returns a promise ( `this.get('results')` ) so I can't use it in my hbs template. Do I need to convert it to an object and then return that object?

Comment: using the words "return" and "promise" together doesn't make much sense to me... you can't convert the promise to anything, you have to wait. what a promise makes it easier to do is instead of bringing the data to the action like php does, it lets you bring the action to the data via a callback. so, you would apply your template in the callback, defined by passing a work-doing function to the then() method on your returned promise object.

Comment: @cat-t You might want to do the search as an action that feeds the `result` property on resolve instead of the way you're doing

Comment: @dandavis promise and return actually do go together. thats how you chain promises. methods that return promises are incredibly useful for function composition

Comment: @sunrize920: "return" in the context of "returned data" (OP), or in the classical sense of a function return, like you see in PHP. the point is that the return happens a lot later that one would think, and you can't see the return from an async lower down in code like you can in sync code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answering the Question

Internally Ember uses a [PromiseProxyMixin](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.PromiseProxyMixin.html) to do the magic rendering of promises that we know and love. Here is your updated JSBin working with a PromiseProxy:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/danazu/edit?html,js,output

Your `results` property becomes this:

```
results: Ember.computed.promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  Ember.$.getJSON('/search').then(function(res) {
    console.log('response data is: ', res);
    return resolve(res);
  });
})
```

However I don't recommend this. Take a look at [this discourse thread](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/promises-and-computed-properties/3333/11) to get some information on why you might not want to do this. In short, it will be clunky to handle all the different states of promises.

### Looking For a Better Way

The Router is the perfect place to deal with promises with AJAX requests. There must be some reason that you're not just loading this data in your Router in the `model` or `afterModel` hooks. Could you create another nested resource to represent these search results and then just `link-to` that resource?

In your Router:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('search', { path: '/search/:term' });
});

App.PeopleRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return Ember.$.getJSON('/search?term=' + params.term);
  }
});
```

If that won't work at the very least you could:

1. Send an `action` when you want the search results
2. Handle the AJAX request in the controller
3. Set the `results` on the controller when they are resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I use [ic ajax](https://github.com/instructure/ic-ajax) for easy use with promises. I don't currently use Ember data so I wrote myself a nice rest client on top of ic ajax to easily get/post/put to urls:

```
rsvpAjax: function(url,method, data){
      var headers = {};

      // build request
      var opts = {};
      var defaultOpts = {
        type: method,
        headers: headers,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: 'json',
        xhrFields: {
          withCredentials: true
        }
      };
      return ajax.request(url, $.extend({}, defaultOpts, opts));
}
```

And then I have get method:

```
getAsync: function(url){
      return this.rsvpAjax(url, "GET");
}
```

Then using it elsewhere in a facade/helper class:

```
import objFactory from 'appname/models/obj';
...
...
foo: function(){
        //get your rest client somehow
        var apiFacade = this.getRestClient();
        return restClient.getAsync('url_string').then(function(response){
            //targets some part of the response - here its an array of 
            var data = response.data;
            return data.map(function(obj){
                return objFactory.create(obj);
            });
        });
}
```

`foo` returns an array of Ember objects. the `objFactory` I import is just a Ember.Object class. The `obj` passed into the create generally is a one to one match with the properties in said Ember.Object. With an initializer, I inject this object into every route:

```
import someFacade from "app/facades/facade";

export default {
    name: 'someFacade',

        initialize: function(container, app) {
        //a singleton by default
        container.register('facades:someFacade',someFacade);
        app.inject('route', 'someFacade', 'facades:someFacade');
    }
};
```

Any of my routes can use this facade without importing it thanks to DI.

```
//Ember blocks
model: function(){
    return this.someFacade.foo();
}
```

or:

```
setupController(controller, model){
    //set controller prop on return of resolved val
    this.someFacade.foo().then(function(foosReslovedVal){
        controller.set('someProp', foosResolvedVal);
    });   
}
```